# How to make all the legend appear in a plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

Im using this code to plot X vector vs all the columns of the table on example.txt

```
C = readtable('example.txt', 'Delimiter',',');
X = 5:5:430;
%%
for i=1:numel(X)
plot(X,C{:,i})
hold on
grid on
end
LegendString = cell(1,numel(X));
hold all
for k = 1:numel(X)
    LegendString{k} = sprintf('%i',X(k));
end
legend(LegendString)
```

Here you can download the example.txt file to run the code:
https://la.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/383371-how-to-make-all-the-legend-appear-in-a-plot

Why the plot is only showing me 50 legends and not all the 86 the code is asking?

Comment: Why cross-post? You have an answer already on MATLAB Answers. Why do you want to waste people's time?

Comment: Also, if you have a legend with more than 3 or 4 entries you're doing it wrong. How is anybody going to be able to distinguish 86 lines???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a Matlab bug, but an intentional behavior: legends are currently limited to `50` elements (you may have noticed that your plot legend contains `50` items in fact, instead of `86`). This limit has probably been introduced in order to avoid the creation of excessively big legends, which:

- are hard to read (especially if they overflow the plot window);
- are computationally expensive to draw;
- occupy a huge volume of memory.

Traces of this hardcoded limit can be found in the legend script itself (in order to view it, run `open legend` in the Command Window). For legends created with explicit labels passed as argument, the limit is probably applied internally somewhere in the class that handles the graphic components of the legend. For legends created without a defined set of labels, the subfunction `set_children_and_strings` applies this limit:

```
if auto_children && length(ch) > 50,
    % only automatically add first 50 to cut down on huge lists
    ch = ch(1:50);
end

matlab.graphics.illustration.internal.generateDisplayNames(ch);
```

In order to overcome this limit, you have two alternatives:

1. select just a few elements to display in the legend;
2. use a workaround by creating one legend for each group of 50 items.

**EDIT**

```
C = readtable('data.txt','Delimiter',',');

X = 5:5:430;
X_len = numel(X);
X_seq = 1:numel(X);

figure();
hold on;
grid on;

h = gobjects(X_len,1);

for i = X_seq
    h(i) = plot(X,C{:,i});
end

legend(h(2:2:X_len),sprintfc('%d',10:10:430));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tommaso, 

my curves are plotted each 5 values until 430, do you know a way to only plot on the legend each 10 values? i.e., the legend would show the curve 10, 20, 30 .. 240.